# Connection speed fast once I start Fiddler

Tags: browser, connection, fiddler, internet-speed

I have two laptops, one of them has no problems whatsoever when it comes to browsing the internet, everything is speedy and pages load as expected.

The other one however, is a nightmare. Pages load slow, and it looks like the browser just sits there and waits a bit before it starts to load pages.

So I installed Fiddler to check the requests that are happening and how long they take to complete.

However, once I start capturing using Fiddler, the browser becomes speedy, and the pages load more or less as on the first laptop.

- So once Fiddler starts, browser speed is normal
- I experience this behavior in all major browsers (chrome, IE, and firefox)
- I have checked the internet options, and there are no proxies configured

Can anyone explain me what is going on?

Comment: Have you verified the laptop in question is virus/malware/spyware free?

Comment: Have you tried visiting pages never visited before to make sure your not getting a cached version? Try running [speed test](http://www.dslreports.com/stest) with and without fiddler running, and try it on the other laptop too.

Comment: @CharlieRB yes, I ran several virus scans and no issues were detected. also I cannot find anything suspicious in the running processes or services.

Comment: @Celeritas the Speed test reveals that the speed is in the same _order of magnitude_ as on the fast pc.

Comment: @thomasvm so that's saying it's not actually faster...

Comment: +1 Interesting question, well worded. :) I would suggest running SysInternal's AutoRuns and ProcMon, and ProcessExplorer to get a better idea of what's running under the hood.

Comment: can be a proxy hijack which the program bypasses. check your proxy settings.

Comment: The behavior seems to be a DNS issue to me. Maybe Fiddler does some extra DNS lookups that makes the browsing experience better?

Comment: Fiddler caches DNS responses, but so do browsers. When you say "no proxies are configured": What *exactly* are the settings inside IE's Tools > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings?

Comment: Do you have "Automatically detect settings" enabled in the Connection tab of Internet Options? If it's on, turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a virus that "hooks" queries of your http port.
If Fiddler uses the same hooking method, it can stop hooks of another "hookers" (in this case - virus).

Thoroughly check your OS for viruses using powerful antiviruses such as Kaspersky IS or Norton IS.
Use `Sysinternals' Autoruns.exe` to check ALL autoruns (because MSConfig doesn't show ALL autoruns). Also use `ProcMon.exe` to see which programs are running and which are using internet when you're connected to the net. These tools will help you to catch virus.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of some hardware problem, maybe in case of the internet adapter of your laptop.

If nothing else solves and if you are willing to spend some money, you can have it replaced with a new one.